# ffmpeg to rip mp3 from mp4 in ruby

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, mp3, system, mp4

Trying to make  basic Ruby script utilising ffmpeg to download a video from Youtube and then rip the mp3 from that video.
Problem is each time the script fails when trying to separate the two, even though the command themselves run fine outside of the.
I think the issue is that Ruby is treating the video as a string, but I'm not sure.

```
def input
    #print "Enter Video URL: "
    #@target_video = gets
    #@target_video ||= ''
    #@target_video.chomp
    @target_video = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYG1qccSUAw'
end

def grab
    #@video = `viddl-rb #{@target_video}`
    `viddl-rb #{@target_video}`
end

def rip
    `ffmpeg -i #{grab} new.mp3`
end

input
rip
```

I tested it in irb and when I tried `@video.class` it returned `string`, I think this is where it's going wrong but I'm not certain.
The video does download successfully but fails on teh rip.

Output and error:

```
ruby youtube_downloader.rb 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 30.4M  100 30.4M    0     0  2580k      0  0:00:12  0:00:12 --:--:-- 2683k
ffmpeg version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 25 2014 19:47:15 with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.3.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --enable-vda --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libavresample   1.  3.  0 /  1.  3.  0
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Loading: No such file or directory
sh: line 1: Plugins: command not found
sh: line 2: Will: command not found
sh: line 3: Analyzing: command not found
sh: line 4: Using: command not found
sh: line 5: [YOUTUBE]: command not found
sh: line 6: [YOUTUBE]: command not found
sh: line 7: Using: command not found
sh: line 8: Download: command not found
sh: line 9: Error:: command not found
sh: line 11: Backtrace:: command not found
sh: -c: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `:27:in'
sh: -c: line 12: `(eval):27:in `initialize''
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is correct?

```
def rip
    `ffmpeg -i #{grab} new.mp3`
end
```

you pass #{grab} that is the method's name instead of #{@video} filename to your rip method.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to change that. Edited it now, shows the same error without assigning the viddl system command to the `@video` variable

Comment: Ah ok @RichardC,
but the `ffmpeg -i` option doesn't expect a filename, it seems you pass something else instead?
BTW viddl-rb exist like gem too, try to go here
[link]https://github.com/rb2k/viddl-rb